# how to display some information of image in another div by clickin on image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to display some information of image in another div by clicking on image and information should be shown/hidden as clicking on this image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cell").click(function () {
        $(this).find("span").toggle("slow");
    })
});



<div class="cell">
        <div class="inner">
          <span style="display:none;"> <img src="Images/sachin.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" /></span>  <span class="name">Sachin Tendulkar</span>
           <input type="hidden" class="friend_id" value="22 " />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want that name displayed in another div when i click on particular image

Comment: What is `.cell` reffering to?

Comment: .cell is referring to parent class of that .inner class

Comment: Can you provide the full html relevant to this question? It's unclear what you're asking without it.

Comment: I have this code. now i will take a new label. i want jQuery code for - when i click on that image ,that image name should be displayed on that new label.

Comment: Your image doesn't *have* a name. Or an `id`. Or any *other* attribute except for the `width`, `height` and `src`. What information do you want to be shown? And from where should it be taken?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think what you're asking is for the name to be displayed when you click on its image?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".inner>img").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find("span").toggle("slow");
    })
});

​<div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="Images/sachin.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="180" />  
      <span class="name" style="display: none;">Sachin Tendulkar</span>
      <input type="hidden" class="friend_id" value="22 " />
    </div>
</div> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Take notice of the reformatted html that removes the `span` around the image (it's not necessary) and the style attributes of your image and name span.

Comment: yes. .i think for this i have to take a variable first and  pass the id of label in it.

Comment: Does this do what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(.cell).click(function() {
    $(this).toggle("slow");
    $(otherDiv).html( $(this).find('span.name').html() );
    // other processing ...
});
```

But this is for your current code, which should be cleaned up a bit. So see below.

You shouldn't need a span to wrap your image. I would try something more along the lines of:

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="Images/sachin.jpg" data-name="Sachin Tendulkar" alt="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="22" class="friend_id" value="22" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Along with:

```
$('.cell').click(function() {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    $(img).toggle('slow');
    $(otherDiv).html( $(img).attr('data-name') );
    // other processing ...
});
```